# VBA - to Loop rows and insert value based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

My Question is about excel VBA looping.  I want the loop to start populating the results from beginning when certain cell values are changed.

I wrote a macro to loop rows and insert value based on condition, however I am experiencing difficulty while including an additional criteria to begin the loop again when the cell value changes.

Condition No. 1 = Should start calculating the time window when the order date time is above 21:00 hours, however i want to loop till new date comes and start populating the window time again from beginning when the next date has 21:00

Considering 1 assignee can work on 10 orders in 1 hour, whereas 2 Assignee can work on 20 orders in 1 hour and so on....

```
Sub EstimatedTimeWindow()
Dim i as long, n as long,
Dim x as double
Dim p as long

    No_of_Orders = 20
    No_of_Assignee  = 2
    OrdersinHour = No_of_Orders  * No_of_Assignee

   Worksheets("final_data").select
   n = cells(rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row
   p = 0

   For i = 2 to n
   x = (1* cells(i,"A")/1)) - Int(Cells(i,"A")) 'to check the time
  If x >= 0.875 'time as 21:00
     p = p + 1
       If p <= OrdersinHour Then
          Cells(i,"B") = "Estimated window time 21:00 - 22:00"
       End If
       If p > OrdersinHour AND p <= OrdersinHour * 2 Then
          Cells(i,"B") = "Estimated window time 22:00 - 23:00"
       End if
       If p > OrdersinHour AND p <= OrdersinHour * 3 Then
          Cells(i,"B") = "Estimated window time 23:00 - 00:00"
       End if
       If p > OrdersinHour AND p <= OrdersinHour * 4 Then
          Cells(i,"B") = "Estimated window time 00:00 - 01:00"
       End if
  End if
Next
End Sub
```

[image: sample_image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misread the question:  I have left that answer below, but it can be ignored.  Updated answer added to the start:

Do not drop the Date from `x` - then, when the day in the cell is not the same as the *previous* row's day, reset `p` to 0

```
For i = 2 to n
    If Int(I) <> Int(cells(I,1).Value Then 'Order Date has changed day
        p = 0 'Reset counter p to 0
    End If
    x = cells(i,1).Value 'to check the time
    If (x mod 1) >= 0.875 'time as 21:00
'Continue as normal
```

<s>You can call a Macro at a specific time with `Application.OnTime` - however, if you close the Workbook but leave Excel open it **will** reopen the Workbook to run the macro unless you disable the `OnTime`.  It gets...  messy.</s>

A better solution would be to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to run code when the values on the Worksheet change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then 'A Cell in Column A changed
        Call EstimatedTimeWindow
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, Quick tweaks to your existing code: `x = Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 1` will give you the time with cleaner code,  the `Hour` statement is easier to read than 0.875 and a `Switch` statement on `p` will make your code cleaner too:

```
For i = 2 to n
    If Int(x) <> Int(Cells(i,1).Value) Then
        p = 0
    End If
    x = Cells(i, 1).Value 'Since we take the Hour, no need to trim the date off first
    If Hour(x) >= 9 Then
        p = p + 1
        Select Case (p\OrdersinHour) 'Same as Int(p/OrdersinHour)
            Case 0:
                Cells(i,2).value = "Estimated window time 21:00 - 22:00"
            Case 1:
                Cells(i,2).value = "Estimated window time 22:00 - 23:00"
            Case 2:
                Cells(i,2).value = "Estimated window time 23:00 - 20:00"
            Case 3:
                Cells(i,2).value = "Estimated window time 00:00 - 01:00"
        End Select
    End IF
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @chronocidal,  just adding the If function to reset the p counter solved my problem.   I added a code    If INT(cells(i,"A").value) <> INT(Cells(i,"A").offset(1,0).value)